# Uso de Foreign Keys Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Boa tarde a todos. 
Criei uma migration "clientes" no laravel que recebe 3 chaves estrangeiras vindas das entidades: modalidades, pedidos e locals.

Na minha view ao cadastrar um cliente e visualizar no phpmyadmin vejo que todos os dados são salvos com seus respectivos nomes, porém nessa minha tabela clientes, as colunas modalidades, pedidos e locals ficam salvos somente o id.

Por exemplo:

No select de modalidade o usuário escolhe o primeiro item do select que é 
Especial.

No select de pedidos o usuário escolhe o segundo item do select que é 
Variados.

No select de locals o usuário escolhe o terceiro item do select que é 
São Paulo.

Se eu for lá no phpmyadmin para ver como ficou no cadastro estará nessas
colunas respectivamente: 1, 2 e 3.

É assim mesmo ou estou fazendo algo errado para não está aparecendo o nome?

Minha migration Clientes está assim:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('nome_cliente',80);
$table->string('email_cliente',80)->unique();
$table->string('endereco',50);
$table->string('situacao',20);
$table->integer('modalidade_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('modalidade_id')->references('id')->on('modalidades');
$table->integer('pedido_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('pedido_id')->references('id')->on('pedidos');
$table->integer('locals_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('locals_id')->references('id')->on('locals');

            $table->softDeletes();

            $table->timestamps();
```

Comment: Está correto, relacionamentos devem ser feitos somente com ID mesmo, quando você for listar os pedidos e nessa listagem exibir o nome do usuário é só você fazer um INNER JOIN.

Comment: Ok, então lá no meu banco vai ficar aparecendo mesmo o ID ao invés do nome?

Comment: Isso mesmo cara.

Answer (score 0):

Chave estrangeira (foreign key) é o campo que estabelece o relacionamento entre duas tabelas.

Assim, **uma coluna corresponde à mesma coluna que é a chave primária de outra tabela**.

Dessa forma, deve-se especificar na tabela que contém a chave estrangeira quais são essas colunas e à qual tabela está relacionada.

O banco de dados irá verificar se todos os campos que fazem referências  à tabela estão especificados, e por padrão a grande maioria dos databases por convenção utilizam-se dos "id"(identificadores) de cada tabela.

Fica mais facil comparar um *int*, do que uma string, não acha? Pois uma string pode conter variações, entre minusculas, maiusculas e tamanhos, já um int, sempre será um int.